# How to auto-create Folders & Files when a Channel is created in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a project to complete, but I need assistance on Power Automate:

1. When A Channel in teams is created, it must go and created the relevant folders in that channel (make use of SharePoint),
2. And fetch templets (Folders & Filles) and store them in a templates folder that Exists

This looks like a simple automate flow but I can't get it right.

This is what I have tried but still can't get it right.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any specific error or issue? It would be more hlepful if you share error detail in specific.

Comment: I have shared most of the details, is it possible for you to help me with a resolution?